MSWord on MacOS Track Changes Balloons message has a typo
MSWord 16.85.2, MacOS Ventura 13.6.7
I'm working in an MS Word document that was created by comparing two documents. I'm using Track Changes with the changes identified in Balloons. The Track Changes Balloons created during the doc comparison correctly say "Deleted:" The Balloons created by deleting anything in the document with Track Changes on have a typo and say "eleted:"
What's up? Does anyone know where the text that MS Word uses in those Balloons is stored and how could I loose the "D"?
I've attached a screenshot showing both Balloons for reference. I've searched the InterWebs and tried various combos of track changes settings, with no luck. BTW - this only happens in this document. It's a 50 page document with hundreds of tracked changes. I don't think it's possible to start over with a clean document.
screenshot showing error condition


It appears that the error condition involved making changes as a user on top of changes that were created when MSWord compared two documents, but not yet "accepted." The fact that the changes were in a Table may have also contributed. I deleted the offending row of the table and then inserted a new row and manually entered the text, all with track changes on. Now won't allow me to track a change on top of another change, since the row is seen as one single change made by me - a user. But, I can live with that.
